# Vb.Net DataGridView code error - Object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am getting error message 'Object reference not set to an instance of object' while trying to loop through the rows in DataGridView in VB.Net

```
     ' This works smooth and returns output as 5
      MsgBox(DtaGrid_Tasks.Rows.Count) 

      'This throws error in first line itself
        For j As Integer = 0 To DtaGrid_Tasks.Rows.Count - 1
            MsgBox(DtaGrid_Tasks.Rows(j).Cells(3).Value.ToString)
        Next

      'Also tried this but getting same error
        For Each dRow As DataGridViewRow In DtaGrid_Tasks.Rows
            'Other codes
        Next
```

Comment: put the `DtaGrid_Tasks.Rows.Count - 1` into a variable before looping maybe and try then?

Comment: Also if a cell is empty  value.tostring will return this error. If there can be empty cells better use Cstr(DtaGrid_Tasks.Rows(j).Cells(3).Value)

Comment: The `Allow User To Add Rows` property is true by default, this creates that bottom blank row used for adding new rows. Set it to false and your code should work. However, if you need the functionality of this `New Row`, then you need to `For j As Integer = 0 To DtaGrid_Tasks.Rows.Count - 2` so as not to try to access it in your loop.

Comment: this issue was resolved. I am using different approach than looping through the cells